# How to write MySQL INSERT trigger for field value based on autoincrement field?

Tags: mysql, triggers

MySQL. I have table with autoincrement primary key field:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
 id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 field VARCHAR(45)
);
```

I want automatically write some field based on primary key value. 
This does not work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 UPDATE myTable SET field=CONCAT(NEW.id,"T") WHERE id=NEW.id;
END;
```

In this case I receive error from MySQL:

> Can`t update table "myTable" in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

And this does not work too:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET NEW.field=CONCAT(NEW.id,"T");
END;
```

In this case NEW.did is undefined.

How can I store some value to `field` based on autoincrement id? Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work with next trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `myTable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `myTable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @new_field = "";
    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO @new_field
        FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name = 'myTable'
        AND table_schema = DATABASE();
    SET NEW.field=CONCAT("A",@new_field);
END;
```

Comment: Be careful with concurrency issues.